# Reference "non-secured" web application?

Tags: web-application

I'm new to both web development and security, and I was wondering whether there is some kind of reference web application that doesn't follow any of the security best practices. Something like a "Security hello world" :).

On OWASP's site there are code examples for almost every threat, I was wondering whether there is an application that would put them all together.

I would like to use it to both test my knowledge while trying to find the flaws, and to run and understand ESAPI with it.

---

Meanwhile a colleague of mine pointed me to [OWASP's complete (and up-to-date) list of deliberately vulnerable web applications](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Vulnerable_Web_Applications_Directory_Project#tab=On-Line_apps). There's so many of them, I really have to work on my googling aptitudes...

Comment: Like [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project)
- [Multidillae](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mutillidae_2_Project)
- [Samurai Dojo](https://github.com/meeas/Samurai-Dojo)
- [Google Gruyere](https://google-gruyere.appspot.com/)
- [Damn Vulnerable Web Application (DVWA)](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)
- [Hack Yourself First](https://hackyourselffirst.troyhunt.com/)

Comment: Add Troy Hunt's hackyourself first to that list, you don't get code but there are 50 or so vulnerabilities to find in his test public website.